# Black vertical line, When using an equirectangular panorama render as an environment texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, panoramic

I have been working on a construction project. I was asked to create a panorama image of a house interior. I decided to go with an equirectangular panorama projection. I did a test render with that.

This was the result:

[image]

I then tried this as an "environment texture" for the "background node". The front came out perfectly but the back had a black vertical line. Here's an image showing just that,[image]

I haven't been unable to reproduce the issue in any other new file.

Here's the screenshots of my camera and render settings.

[image]

I am using the proper 2:1 ratio, but this issue still occurs. Any ideas to what might be causing this?

**Edit:**

Here's the node setup,

[image]

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of the node setup where you used the texture?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have added the node setup

Comment: "Border" is checked. Why?

Comment: You definitely have a black border around the texture...the problem is with the rendering not the usage later.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.  I will uncheck that and let you know